How can I comment several lines at once in VSC?
I tried to comment several lines at once using ctrl+/ and ctrl+shift+A but neither worked. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?
I tried these shortcuts hoping that the lines that I highlighted would be turned into a comment by putting a hashtag in front of it.

If you put your cursor at the start of the line, the press Shift-Alt-Down through your block, it creates a multi-line cursor.  Now you can press #, and it gets inserted on all those lines.

Select block of code then Ctrl + '/' (next to right ctrl)

To reviewers... Visual Studio Code is for sure a tool commonly used by developers, and OP is asking how to do a common programming task. There may be valid reasons to close (is this a duplicate?), but it's definitely not "not about programming or software development".

You could use shortcuts Ctrl+/ to comment the selected lines.
Read keyboard-shortcuts for more information.

